# use Dojo to add an onclick event for a series of img

Tags: image, dojo

A button is clicked to trigger LoadImages method to load a series of pictures into the web page. I want to add an onclick event for each picture so when user click it, the picture name is displayed. How to use Dojo to achieve this?

```js
LoadImages(PictureNames){
     var resultUl = new Builder('<ul />');
     for (i = 0; i < PictureNames.length; i++){
        resultUl.append('<li><img id=' + PictureNames[i] + ' src="./images/' + PictureNames[i] + '.jpg" height="200" width="250" class="photo"/></li>');
     }
     dom.byId('Pictures').innerHTML = resultUl;
}

DisplayPictureName(picturename)
{
 dom.byId('PictureName').value = picturename; 
}
```

```html
<label id="PictureName">here displays picture name</label>
<div id="Pictures"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the elements using `dojo/dom-construct` and attach events using `dojo/on`.

```
     var resultUl = domConstruct.create('ul');
     for (i = 0; i < PictureNames.length; i++){
        var image= domConstruct.create('img', {
                            id: PictureNames[i]',
                            src: "./images/"+ PictureNames[i],
                            style: {"height: 200px; width: 250px"},
                            class: "photo"});
        var li= domConstruct.create('li');
        domConstruct.place(li, resultUl);
        domConstruct.place(image, li);
        dojo.on(image, 'click', this.DisplayPictureName());
     }
     dom.byId('Pictures').innerHTML = resultUl;
```

Comment: thanks. the resultUl from above codes has only <ul></ul>. no other img elements were placed. any thoughts why?

Comment: There is only one reason that I can think of because of which there will be an empty list and it is that your `PictureNames` array is empty.

Comment: somehow, the var li= domConstruct.create('li', resultUl); doesn't work for me. the following syntax worked. var li = domConstruct,create('li'); domConstruct.place(li, resultUl);

Comment: I just found another issue. the click event was fired automatically when an image was being loaded. not sure how to fix that?

Comment: changed to dojo.on(image, 'click', function(){this.DisplayPicturename()}); worked.

Comment: actually the codes didn't work properly.  DisplayPictureName always displays the last record in the PictureNames. any thoughts?

Comment: Sorry for the first mistake. I have corrected my code also. Regarding the last record display, what are you passing to the `DisplayPictureName` function and how is the name computed?

Comment: dojo.on(image, 'click', function(){this.DisplayPictureName(PictureName[i])}); within DisplayPictureName function, I do some matching from another array to get picture name based on picture id match and then display the name on the web page.

Comment: And you are getting correct picture name in `DisplayPictureName` function when it is called? Have you checked that?

Comment: Himanshu, I couldn't post codes in the comment. so i posted another question. i would appreciate if you can test it at yoru end why that happened. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37418651/using-dojo-to-programmaticaly-add-a-list-of-images-and-add-a-click-event-for-eac

Comment: instead of using a for loop, using an array solved the problem.thanks for your help!