# using Dojo to programmaticaly add a list of images and add a click event for each of them

Tags: javascript, dom, dojo

I am loading a list of images and adding a click event to each of them using Dojo so when user clicks an image, the ID for that image gets displayed. Please see codes below. Images were loaded, but when I click each of them, only '10143' was written in the log. any ideas why that happened? Please help!

```js
var PictureIds = ['10141', '10142', '10143'];
var resultUl = domConstruct.create('ul');
for (i = 0; i < PictureIds.length; i++){
  var image= domConstruct.create('img', {
    id: PictureIds[i],
    src: "./images/"+ PictureIds[i] + ".jpg",
    class: "photo"});

  var li= domConstruct.create('li');
  domConstruct.place(image, li);
  domConstruct.place(li, resultUl);

  on(image, 'click', function(){
    console.log(image.id);
  });
}
domConstruct.place(resultUl,'pictures');
```

```html
<div id="pictures"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to use `dojo/array` instead of for loop. Also you should create your images at the beggining of your code. Then add them in an array and make a loop on that array in order to add them to the dom.

I am giving an example below but I am using paragraph tags instead of images for simplicity. 
You can do what I am doing on the example below but instead of creating paragraphs you can create images.

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/an90dr/493khnug/

Comment: Does not have to do with for loop. There is nothing wrong using for loop. But while you are using dojo it is best practice to use 'dojo/array'. Here is another working example using for loop. 

https://jsfiddle.net/an90dr/493khnug/10/